# Difference between the 2 approaches to find probabilities

Tags: python, numpy, probability

Ask: set step to 0 with a 20% chance

Approach 1

```
#seed set at 123
abc=(1,2,3,4,5)
#as 1 has 20% chance of being picked from the list..
if np.random.choice(abc)==1:
    step = 0
else step=100
```

Approach 2

```
#seed set at 123
if np.random.rand() <= 0.2 :
    step = 0
else step=100
```

Which one is correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first one is a tiny bit more precise because of discretization error in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

This two approaches should give the same result.
You can test it by calculate average  % of cases where step=0, and repeat calculations many times, for example 10000000 times:

```
np.random.seed(123)
print(np.mean(np.random.rand(10000000)<0.2))
print(np.mean(np.random.choice((1,2,3,4,5), 10000000)==1))
```

result is pretty close to 20%:

```
0.1999137
0.1999221
```